# How to specify JDBC timestamp in Swagger API request?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, swagger, openapi

I want to receive (nullable) start and end times, which I've declared in my Swagger yaml:

> ```
>     start:
>       type: string
>       format: date-time
>     end:
>       type: string
>       format: date-time
> ```

which correspond to these JPA columns:

> ```
> @Column(name = "start_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
> private Timestamp start;
>
> @Column(name = "end_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
> private Timestamp end;
> ```

But I keep getting this error:

> String must be in JDBC format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffffff] to
> create a java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: Have you tried using a `java.time.Instant` on your API then using `Timestamp.from(instant)` to save it in your DB?

Comment: By the way… To track specific moments, you should be using database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than `WITHOUT`. And on the Java side, use the *java.time* types, never use `java.sql.Timestamp` class.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's necessary for me to use java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: [`format: date-time`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#format) is for [RFC 3339](https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14)-style date-time, i.e. with `T` between the date and time parts. It shouldn't be used for other date formats. The issue can probably be fixed by removing `format: date-time` from your OpenAPI YAML file.

Comment: @Helen Even without date-time, the error still persists